# Pandas : How to avoid fillna while resampling from hourly to daily data

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I have a Series which consists of hourly data. I want to compute daily sum. 
The data may have missing hours and sometimes missing dates.

```
2017-02-01 00:00:00  3.0
2017-02-01 01:00:00  4.0
2017-02-01 02:00:00  4.0
2017-02-03 00:00:00  3.0
```

For example, in the time series above for 2017-02-01, only first three hours data is present. Rest of the 21 hours data is missing.

The data for 2017-02-02 is completely missing.

1. I don't care about missing hours. The daily sum should consider whatever data is present for a day (in the example, it should consider hours 0, 1, 2).
2. But, if a date is completely missing, I should have NaN as the sum for that date.

resample() followed by sum() works fine for #1. But it returns me 0 for #2.

```
2017-02-01  110.0
2017-02-02  0.0
2017-02-03  3.0
```

Here is the dummy code:

```
my_series.resample('1D',closed='left',label='left').sum()
```

How can I tell resample(), not to set 0 for missing dates?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `min_count=1` in [`sum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html):

> **min_count** : int, default 0
> The required number of valid values to perform the operation. If fewer than min_count non-NA values are present the result will be NA.
>
> New in version 0.22.0: Added with the default being 0. This means the sum of an all-NA or empty Series is 0, and the product of an all-NA or empty Series is 1.

```
a = my_series.resample('1D',closed='left',label='left').sum(min_count=1)
print (a)
2017-02-01    11.0
2017-02-02     NaN
2017-02-03     3.0
Freq: D, Name: a, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Awesome! I went to get a cup of tea and you solved the problem which I am dealing with for last 2 hours. Thanks! I should have looked into the documentation here : https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.resample.Resampler.sum.html#pandas.core.resample.Resampler.sum